# Data storing multiple times

Tags: angular, typescript, service

```
public submit(item): Observable<any> {
console.log("****",temp);
const request = base.pipe(
map((data: TokenResponse) => {
console.log('Ans data',data);
return data;

    })
  );
return request;
}
```

**Above is my service where I iterate the array and pass that to backend**

**Data is inserted correctly but the problem is after some time, data is inserted multiple times. Please help me, fix it.
Post request to users/submit is sent multiple times.
Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

You have created a query inside a `forEach`,so therefore depending on the number of elements in the `forEach`, your query will be run that many times.
Try this:

```
exports.submit = function(req, res) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  let element = req.body;
    console.log("inside for req.body 1", element);
   connection.query(
      "INSERT INTO user_answer(Test_Taker_User_id,Schedule_id,Question_id,Chosen_Answer_id, Created_By) Values(?,?,?,?,?)",
      [user_id, user_schedule_id, element[1], element[0], username],
      function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
        //  console.log("error ocurred", error);        
        }

        Results = results;
        console.log("*****************************************");
      //console.log("inside element RESULTS:", Results);
      }
    );

};
```

Comment: Not working, nothing is inserted if I don't use foreach

Comment: when you console.log `request.body` what do you see?

Comment: I have 10 elements, I want all the 10 elements to be inserted in DB. But the 10 elements are inserted twice, that's the problem.